# Data Tables in Tab Control Metro UI CSS

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, metro-ui-css

can you help me how to use data tables in controll tabs with Metro UI Framework.
The data tables using this framework: http://www.datatables.net/. I have tried to implement it in controll tabs in Metro UI(http://metroui.org.ua/tab-control.html). But data tables cant be show, and got error in java script. The code below:

```
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/metro/metro.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/metro/metro.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/metro/metro-tab-control.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "paging":   false,
            "ordering": false,
            "info":     false
        } );
    } );
</script>
<div class="tab-control" data-role="tab-control">
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#_page_1">Anggota PTK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#_page_2">Peserta Didik</a></li>   
                <li class="place-right"><a href="#_page_5"><i class="icon-plus-2"></i> Tambah Akun</a></li>             
            </ul>

            <div class="frames">
                <div class="frame" id="_page_1"><?php include "admin_viewdata_ptk.php";?></div>
                <div class="frame" id="_page_2"><?php include "admin_viewdata_peserta.php";?></div>
                <div class="frame" id="_page_5"><?php include "admin_user_adduser.php";?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Please give me clue or solution.thanks

Comment: Are you referencing your source of datatable to be attached to? $('#example').dataTable( ), here #example should be your div or html table name that you want to serve as a data table. Please follow > http://www.datatables.net/manual/installation

Comment: Of course, in reference file .html contain table which id name "example". But if i not using controll tab, the data tables work properly. So how to implement data tables in cotroll tab?

Comment: i have solved these problem, the problem occurs because i have duplicated call java script library.thanks for your attention